# Are there anyother method under research for curing rabies?

Tags: pathology, antibody

Why is rabies incurable after onset of symptoms? Although we administer HRIG (lyssa virus antibody) to the patient, why doesn't it work after onset of symptoms? And are there any other successful treatments for rabies like that of Milwaukee protocol which are under research? I also want to know how successful  is Milwaukee protocol so far?

Comment: Antibody wont cross blood brain barrier. Rabies virus infects the hippocampus.